# [ros2] Prefix in launch file

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS 1 launch files allowed to run nodes in a debugger, e.g. using `launch_prefix="gdb --args"`. I tried to use it with ROS 2 by adding this parameter to `launch_ros.actions.Node`, but it just caused parsing errors. Is there still a way to specify such a prefix in ROS 2 launch files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343326/%5Bros2%5D-prefix-in-launch-file/) by [hdino](https://answers.ros.org/users/44997/hdino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2020-02-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**EDIT**

There is new discussion about this answer not being able to interact with GDB because launch doesn't allow a process to access stdin. That discussion is [on an issue in the launch_ros repo](https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/issues/165#issuecomment-686635595).

[One workaround is to add `xterm -e` to the start of the prefix](https://github.com/samsung-ros/gdb_test_pkg/pull/1/files) to open an new xterm window with the process. In this case, use the prefix `xterm -e gdb -ex=r --args`.

There's another very similar question and answer in #q267261

---

**Original answer**

`launch_ros.actions.Node` inherits from `launch.actions.ExecuteProcess`, and it passes extra arguments given to `__init__` to it. I think you're looking for [prefix](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/4333910ba41977f3ab9867082c86a8698ada3a16/launch/launch/actions/execute_process.py#L101).

Save this file as `gdb_pub_launch.py`

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch import LaunchService

import launch_ros.actions


def generate_launch_description():
    """Run demo nodes via launch."""
    ld = LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='demo_nodes_cpp', node_executable='talker', output='screen',
            remappings=[('chatter', 'my_chatter')],
            prefix=['gdb -ex=r --args'],
        )
    ])
    return ld
```

And run with

```
ros2 launch gdb_pub_launch.py
```

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8